# NoMethodError in Controller#create - undefined method `level' for... impossible to save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, save, nomethoderror, levels

I am building a ruby on rails app.
I have problems to create an Outfit.
It throws an error I don't understand

> NoMethodError in OutfitsController#create
> undefined method `level' for

But I have nothing named level in any of my code .. I don t get it !
here is the screenshot [screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41mR9.png), and my code.

```
 def create
    @user = current_user
    @outfit = Outfit.new(outfit_params)
    @outfit.user = current_user
    if @outfit.save
      redirect_to outfits_path
      flash[:notice] = "Outfit created"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Something went wrong, please check the form again"
    end
  end

 private

  def outfit_params
    params.require(:outfit).permit(:name, :pet, :price, :color, :style, :size, :description, photos:[])
  end

  def update_outfit_params
    params.require(:outfit).permit(:name, :pet, :price, :color, :style, :size,:description,  photos:[])
  end
```

I tried to use @outfit.save!
no succes, it always tells me " NoMmethod 'level' ..."!
That's what I don't get, never happened before.. where does that 'level' come from ?

Here is my model

```
class Outfit < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many_attached :photos

  SIZE = ['S', 'M', 'L']
  validates_inclusion_of :level, :in => SIZE

end
```

Comment: -->  validates_inclusion_of *:level* -- right there in your model -- remove the validation or change to validates_inclusion_of *:size*

Comment: is there a 'level' field on your Outfit table ? 
how it's not listed in your outfit_params ?
what is the content of your outfit_params in the creation method can you provide an example ?